# JSP pages - same name different directories

Tags: java, jsp, websphere

Forgive me if this is a dumb question, I've looked around I was unable to find an answer (even if this seems to be a dumb question).

Anyway, looking at java classes generated by JSP pages I've found that there are two classes with the same name and same package in two different directories.

So for example I have two different jsp pages (they have only the same name but different source code):

```
./mobile20/ShoppingArea/CategoriesDisplayMetadata.jsp
./ShoppingArea/CategoriesDisplayMetadata.jsp
```

And Websphere generates two java classes:

```
./mobile20/ShoppingArea/_CategoriesDisplayMetadata.java
./ShoppingArea/_CategoriesDisplayMetadata.java
```

But looking at the java classes for both of them inside there is:

```
package com.ibm._jsp;

public final class _CategoriesDisplayMetadata extends com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase
     implements com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.JspClassInformation {
[...]
```

I suppose that Websphere class loader can load only one right? The other java class even if correctly generated cannot be loaded by Websphere, right?

Comment: That would be a pretty crippling restriction; consider `index.jsp` - that's a very common one (and I know that works in multiple directories in WAS).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch right, thanks. So, would be nicer knowing how it works.

Comment: You can think of the package com.ibm._jsp as being 'local' to the directory its under.  There is no 'crosstalk' with JSP's of the same name in different directories in the war, unless you import explicitly.